# Ignoring duplicated primary keys when exporting data from one database to another in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, export, primary-key

I am currently trying to export the past 3 months of data from a table on my SQL Server to a new table in a new database (same columns etc but slightly different primary keys). I get an error when doing this because there is a duplicated primary key in the new table.. I was wondering whether there is a way to ignore this error or only insert 1 of the values in which this primary key conflict is happening.

So far I have

```
SELECT * 
FROM [action] 
WHERE systemdatetime < getdate() 
    AND systemdatetime > DATEADD(month, -3, getdate())
```

And I am currently using the export wizard

Comment: how would you choose which rows don't get copied? you can use a `group by` on the PK columns to get distinct results... but then you need to decide what aggregates make sense.  Another choice would be `rank` your rows by PK and select `rank=1` rows.

Comment: Well the information in both row is identical. I was hoping there was an amendment to my SQL statement to test whether the primary key already exists and so not try to insert a duplicate (which errors the wizard)

Comment: if they are fully identical then just group on all fields. you won't get any duplicate rows that way.

Comment: That is a good solution. The only problem is when I said identical. I meant kind of identical (i.e. not identical), So in my case this wouldnt work and the problem would still exist

Comment: so then we are back to the first question of how do you decide which one to keep? otherwise there is no way to answer...

Comment: I would just keep whichever one got there first essentially

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61061/discussion-between-daniel-e-and-user1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your PK field is called but lets say it is ID. You can do this to number the records that all had the same id, then just pull out the first one from each sequence.  Notice I ordered this by the date so the earliest date would be the one selected.

```
SELECT ID, systemdatetime, etc..
FROM (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY systemdatetime) Row
  FROM [action] 
  WHERE systemdatetime < getdate() 
    AND systemdatetime > DATEADD(month, -3, getdate())
) tmp
WHERE Row = 1
```

Comment: This looks like the solution I need apart from i get an error on the word tmp `(no column was specified for column 13 of tmp)` and on the word Row `(invalid column name row)`

Comment: Instead of select *, you need to make sure you NAME each return column. Otherwise you get this error.  You cannot have a nested select return an un-named column.

Comment: The error was I missed out the word `Row` after the partition

Answer (score 0):

Create an unkeyed copy of your target table and dump your data into that. From there, you can decide what is really unique and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should create primary key on the another database table with index option `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`, if you don't want to store duplicate rows